# running a jar example file with hadoop

Tags: java, linux, hadoop, bigdata

Please go easy on me. I just started linux and hadoop at the same time. I have almost zero experience with linux and a complete beginner with hadoop.

I downloaded the file `hadoop-1.1.1-bin.tar.gz` from here:

http://www.motorlogy.com/apache/hadoop/common/hadoop-1.1.1/

I was able to unpack it.

I am following a tutorial that tells me to run:

```
bin/hadoop jar hadoop-*-examples.jar
```

I am getting this error:

```
agordon@Ubuntu32:/hadoop/hadoop-1.1.1$ bin/hadoop jar hadoop-*-examples-1.0.3.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Error opening job jar: hadoop-*-examples-1.0.3.jar
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:90)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: hadoop-*-examples-1.0.3.jar (No such file or directory)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:214)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:144)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:152)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:89)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:88)
```

What am i doing wrong? thank you for your guidance.

Comment: Maybe try to replace `hadoop-*-examples.jar` with the actual jar file name.  Perhaps they used the * as a placeholder to make their tutorial applicable across multiple versions

Comment: @foampile thanks so much for your comment. i think its actually part of the syntax: http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.20.2/quickstart.html  would you agree?

Comment: I think @foampile is right. First thing you need to learn when using linux is to believe the error messages " hadoop-*-examples-1.0.3.jar (No such file or directory)" :-) ... Note the literal star that you passed in wasn't expanded as a filename.  Look for the jar file ending in `examples-1.0.3.jar` and then copy/paste that full name into your cmd line. Good luck

Comment: @shellter thank you very much. where would the file be?

Comment: go to the dir that you unpacked the `*.tar.gz` file, and run `find . -name '*examples-1.0.3.jar'`. Then you can use `bin/hadoop jar $path/to/jar/discovered/with/find/....examples..jar`. Good luck.

Comment: @foampile  thank you both!! you are both right!! i was able to find the file and it was called examples-1.1.1.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of hadoop-*-examples.jar use the full name of the jar file.